# Python Converts Float Incorrectly

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here? This is using Python 2.7.11:

```
print float(148.95)
print float(148.95)*100
print int(float(148.95)*100)
```

Why does this print:

```
148.95
14895.0
14894 <--- Shouldn't this be 14895?
```

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

148.95 is not a number that can be exactly represented using floating point. The number internally stored is actually `148.94999999999998863131622783839702606201171875`. When you multiply by a hundred, you get `14894.999999999998181010596454143524169921875`. When you convert that to integer, it cuts off the .999... and you're left with 14894.

If you want a data type that can exactly represent numbers with at least two decimal places of precision, consider using `Decimal`.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> x = Decimal("148.95")
>>> print x
148.95
>>> print x*100
14895.00
>>> print int(x*100)
14895
```

Comment: The comment that I heard was, "floating point number like little pile of sand on the ground.  Each time you pick it up and move it around, you lose a little sand and pick up a little dirt."  Also remember that, when you *print* it, you are seeing a character, base-*ten*, representation of an internal, base-*two*, floating-point value.  These characteristics are typical of all computer languages, and are basically unavoidable.  "It's just how the thing works ..."  (And by "the thing," I mean, "the computer!")